# Split 1 column into multiple columns with up to 500 cells each

Tags: google-sheets

In Google Sheets, I have a column that is arbitrarily long.

I want to split this column into separate columns of length 500.

How can I do this?

Some things I've been thinking may be involved in a solution:

- [TRANSPOSE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262)
- [ARRAY_CONSTRAIN](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en)

Answer (score 3):

### Update 2023

With new Google Sheets functions whis became much easier:

`=WRAPROWS(A2:A15,5,"")`

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13184285?hl=en

---

`Arrayformula`, an example for number 5, change to 500.

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR( vlookup( (TRANSPOSE(ROW(INDIRECT("a1:a"&ROUNDUP(COUNTA(A:A)/5))))-1)*5 + ROW(INDIRECT("a1:a"&5)), {ROW(A:A),A:A},2,) ))`

[image]

- `ROUNDUP(COUNTA(A:A)/5` the number of columns. `Up` because the last column may contain less than N rows.
- `TRANSPOSE(...)*5 + ROW(INDIRECT("a1:a"&5))` to get matrix of numbers.

Matrix:

```
1   6   11  16
2   7   12  17
3   8   13  18
4   9   14  19
5   10  15  20
```

- `{ROW(A:A),A:A}` to get the number of a row and value to return
- `vlookup` to return a value
- `IFERROR` to show "" if error.

Answer (score 0):

Having an arbitrarily long column implies you'll need arbitrarily many columns for the split, and spreadsheet formulas cannot create new columns. So the best we can is to use all columns available.

Assuming the data column begins with cell A1, and the  upper left corner of the range in which it should be split is B1, the following formula will work, if you fill the first 500 rows of the sheet with it:

```
=offset($A$1, row()-row($B$1) + 500*(column()-column($B$1)), 0)
```

Otherwise, change A1 and B1 to the top source and upper-left corner of destination.

Explanation: the offset moves from A1 down by the specified amount, which increments by 1 with every row and by 500 with every column.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use this formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
    TRIM(
        SPLIT(
            TRANSPOSE(
                SPLIT(
                    QUERY(
                        <long_column_range> & "," & IF(
                            MOD(1, <columns>) = 0, "|", ""
                        ),, 9^9
                    ), "|"
                )
            ), ","
        )
    )
)
```

where:

1. `<long_column_range>` is the range of the long column that you want to split (e.g. `A1:A`) and
2. `<columns>` is the number of columns that you want for the long column to be split into.

Taken from [this article](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/split-a-column-into-multiple-n-columns-sheets/).